# "Failed to update your invite code" when trying to alter language settings

Tags: uber

I'm trying to alter my language settings on the Uber web application.

However, I'm receiving the following error:

> Failed to update your invite code. Please try again.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It could be a browser issue. Clear the cache and try. Try with other browsers as well once just to check if it works or not.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after trying all sorts of setting changes.  Turns out it had successfully changed my language anyhow.